# Scrapy - Extract text from table

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm playing around with scrapy, but I haven't figured out how to extract the text I want.

My parse function looks like this at the moment

```
def parse(self, response):
        itemList = response.css("#mw-content-text > table.wikitable > tr")
        for item in itemList[1:]:
            print(item.css("td:nth-child(2)").get())
            print(item.css("td:nth-child(2)::text").get())
            print(item.css("td:nth-child(2) > span::text").get())
```

The first selection `item.css("td:nth-child(2)").get()` selects the correct table cell which looks like this

```
<td> <span class="sortkey" style="display:none"><span style="display:none">000000000000010.0000000000</span>10</span>1 - 10 </td>
```

Now I want the text of this cell `1 - 10`, but the second selector `item.css("td:nth-child(2)::text").get()` returns nothing.

The third one `td:nth-child(2) > span::text").get()` is working again and returns `10`.

My questions is what is wrong with the second selection and how do I get the text of the table cell?

Comment: You should share the excerpt of HTML code from which you are trying to extract this data.